# Back to the same color

Tags: jquery, css, animation

```
$(".color").hover(function(){
$(this).animate({ backgroundColor: 'red' });
},function(){
$(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '' });
});
```

I want to animate the background color of different div.
Does it's possible to have the original color when the mouse is out the div ?

- http://jsfiddle.net/9AAGJ/

Comment: Why don't you use CSS3?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to save the BG color to the element before changing away from it. Here I save it in a data-attribute:

```
$(".color").hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('bg-color', $this.css('backgroundColor'));
    $this.animate({ backgroundColor: 'red' });
},function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: $this.data('bg-color') });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gunderson/9AAGJ/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through css only

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/9AAGJ/3/)**

```
.pink:hover, .cyan:hover, .green:hover {
    background-color:red;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
(function () 
    var original;
    $(".color").hover(function () {
        original = $(this).css('background-color');
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor: original
        });
    });
());
```

that function wrapper is to prevent creating a global original variable you can remove it if you want.